# Is there a place for "E.G. images we can hot-link in code examples"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, images, imgur, code-examples

For a long time on Stack Overflow, I have been encouraging people to hot-link to images in code samples that involve images.  An easy way to do that is to upload the image to the question and then use that link in the code.

This is particularly handy for situations involving HTML/JS/CSS, as well as in any programming language that can easily support hot-linking to images (e.g. Java).

I want to establish a 'Community Wiki' Q&A on SO that includes the image tag, as well as several of the most relevant tags of technologies that can use it (e.g. those listed above), and as an answer, add a variety of 'free for use' images.  Animated and non animated GIFs, tile and sprite sets, PNG with partial transparency, JPEGs that can be used in slideshows etc.

The images I am looking to include are either previously generated (by me) using Java, or photographs I've taken (for the JPEGs).  They are mostly small in size (WxH) and all under 40Kb (that is the target, at least).

The trouble is, I feel this is skating on the edge of 'off-topic' for SO.  Note, I'd prefer not to do such a thread on Meta, unlike [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post), but if deemed 'off-topic' for SO, and 'on-topic' for Meta, it will do (though we lose the language tags).

*Would such a Community Wiki Q&A be off-topic for SO?  (Failing that) Would it be off-topic for Meta?*

### See also

I was looking over these Q&As to try and find an answer, but none of them address the exact question I need answered.

- [Pulling old hotlinked images into imgur account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161921/155831)
- [Are Hotlinked images allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32813/155831)
- [How do I do a "good" code dump for a comprehensive example?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111312/155831)

### Image Examples

#### Definite inclusions

- [Proper way to use JLabels to update an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819528/proper-way-to-use-jlabels-to-update-an-image/18825844#18825844)  (the Mercator maps - images 2 & 3).  Good for left/right scrolling animations, since they join up at the edges.
- ['Fill' Unicode characters in labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686753/418556) (the 3rd - 5th images).  Sprite sets of chess pieces.
- [Animating dashed-line with java.awt.BasicStroke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9772978/418556) (small animated GIF).
- [Geometric Shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052085/418556) - the 4 colors x 5 shapes are handy for button (menu, frame..) icons.
- [These 5 images](http://pscode.org/media/#image) that I'd added to my PSCode.org site, explicitly for hot-linking and free use.
- [2 images from 1point1C.org](http://1point1c.org/) (another of my sites), specifically two sizes of the animated GIF seen at http://1point1c.org/gif/thum/plnttm.gif & http://1point1c.org/gif/plnt/orbit.gif

#### Possible inclusions

- [Pacman open/close mouth animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14437899/418556) (the first 4 animated images, or the last 4 non animated images that can be made into an animation).  Though I note that 'time and technology' has not been kind to those images (they seem to be reduced to far fewer colors than they originally contained).
- [How to resize text in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440543/418556) (possible - though I can think of better ways to show anything that image portrays).

#### Rejected for stated reason

- [Image/Graphic into a Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059497/418556) The 2nd image.  I feel it is a 'derived work' and thereby my copyright, but the folks at ShutterStock might disagree, and I don't wish to get into an argument with them.
- [Add a complex image in the panel, with buttons around it in one customized user interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).  While this question embeds a great little tileset for buttons, I did not create it, and am uncertain of its origin or  copyright.

Comment: There is placehold.it (example: http://placehold.it/200x200) - generates a 200px by 200px img.

Comment: @JoshC  Java can produce a transparent or black filled image in a single line of code (without hot linking to an 'off site'(1) resource).  I am after something a little more subtle.. images in multiple colors or shapes, animated GIFs with/without transparency, JPEGs that are 'pairs' of pictures that be used in image transitions, tile sets, sprite sets..  1) OK - technically imgur is 'off-site', but I think it is considered to be 'on-site' when it comes to images embedded in SO/SE questions & answers.

Comment: I don't know - I didn't fully read what you had written when I suggested that. There are several placeholding image services out there. I do, however, think this is a good idea - having placeholding images on SO.. interesting post 1+

Comment: @JoshC One can use http://placekitten.com/200/200 for placeholders that are 100% cuter ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this question has not attracted any answers in two days, I decided to go ahead with the 'acid test' and just try it.

See [Place for example images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556) for the result.

---

Whatever the theory is, the reality seems to be that the community will take it gracefully (in accepting it does more good than harm) and not vote to close the question.  That is, as long is it is seen to be of value - guessing by the votes.

Comment: Seems like this could be moved to MSO now that we have it. It is basically meta, though I've never personally thought it a problem to be on the main site.

Comment: (The [actual Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556) I mean.)